# Response.Redirect and masterpage

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page in my ASP.Net application. I have a Menu inside a master page which redirects to its own content pages. All the pages are derived from the same masterpage.
each time a redirect happens from One page to another the Master Page is loaded. Is there a way that we can avoid MasterPage to reload after redirection happens.

To be precise I want to know can we prevent Masterpage from reloading on Response.redirect.

Comment: Do you mean you do not want to inherit the sitemaster in certain circumstances? or is it just page load?

Comment: It is just Pageload I am talking of. I just need to have something like !IsPostback to work on Masterpage when a redirection happens from one content page to the other.

Answer (score 1):

A response Redirect is a page refresh so the master page *has* to reload.

The way around it is to use an AJAX call and refresh only your content areas.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that we can avoid MasterPage to reload after redirection happens?

No!
Please read "[Run-time Behavior of Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)" from the MSDN doc.